# Normalize a flat data structure with ansible

Tags: json, ansible, terraform

I'm currently attempting to normalize a flat data structure that I receive from a terraform output, so that information can be better processed by subsequent operations. Where I work the preference is to use Ansible for these types of tasks, but I'm open to solutions using Python if it would substantially simplify the task. Below is an example input (sanitized) and the desired output from that input.

Input:

```
{
  "ebs_block_device.0000000000.device_name": "/dev/xvdc",
  "ebs_block_device.0000000000.volume_id": "vol-00000000000000000",
  "ebs_block_device.0000000000.volume_size": "120",
  "ebs_block_device.0000000000.volume_type": "standard",
  "ebs_block_device.1111111111.device_name": "/dev/xvde",
  "ebs_block_device.1111111111.volume_id": "vol-11111111111111111",
  "ebs_block_device.1111111111.volume_size": "80",
  "ebs_block_device.1111111111.volume_type": "standard",
  "ebs_block_device.2222222222.device_name": "/dev/xvdf",
  "ebs_block_device.2222222222.volume_id": "vol-22222222222222222",
  "ebs_block_device.2222222222.volume_size": "50",
  "ebs_block_device.2222222222.volume_type": "standard",
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "devices": [
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/xvdc",
      "volume_id": "vol-00000000000000000",
      "volume_size": "120",
      "volume_type": "standard"
    },
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/xvde",
      "volume_id": "vol-11111111111111111",
      "volume_size": "80",
      "volume_type": "standard"
    },
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/xvdf",
      "volume_id": "vol-22222222222222222",
      "volume_size": "50",
      "volume_type": "standard",
    }   
  ]  
}
```

### Attempts thus far

Using the following ansible I am able to get close to the desired output, I just can't seem to find the right filter, json_query filter or other such trick to alter the keys.

Tasks:

```
- name: "Get input from file"
  set_fact:
    device_data: "{{ lookup('file', file_path) | from_json | dict2items }}"

- name: "Extract list of volume id numbers created by terraform"
  vars:
    ebs_regex: "ebs_block_device\\.(\\d*)\\.device_name"
  set_fact:
    volume_id_list: 
      "{{ device_data 
      | selectattr('key', 'match', ebs_regex) 
      | map(attribute='key')
      | map('regex_replace', ebs_regex, '\\1')
      | list }}"

# using '| to_json | from_json |' is a known workaround for a common string typing issue in json_query
# For more information see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299
- name: "Organize volumes into list"
  vars:
    query_text: "[?contains(key, '{{ item }}')]"
    single_volume: "{{ device_data | to_json | from_json | json_query(query_text) }}"
  set_fact:
    volume_data: "{{ volume_data | default([]) + [single_volume | items2dict] }}"
  loop:
    "{{ volume_id_list }}"

- debug: var=volume_data
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "volume_data": [
        {
            "ebs_block_device.2659407853.device_name": "/dev/xvdf"
            "ebs_block_device.2659407853.volume_id": "vol-00000000000000000",
            "ebs_block_device.2659407853.volume_size": "50",
            "ebs_block_device.2659407853.volume_type": "standard"
        },
        {
            "ebs_block_device.2630216116.device_name": "/dev/xvde"
            "ebs_block_device.2630216116.volume_id": "vol-11111111111111111",
            "ebs_block_device.2630216116.volume_size": "80",
            "ebs_block_device.2630216116.volume_type": "standard"
        },
        {
            "ebs_block_device.2554893574.device_name": "/dev/xvdc"
            "ebs_block_device.2554893574.volume_id": "vol-22222222222222222",
            "ebs_block_device.2554893574.volume_size": "120",
            "ebs_block_device.2554893574.volume_type": "standard"
        }
    ]
}
```

### The Question

How can I alter the values of the keys in my results, either before or after constructing the desired data structure? If this is not possible, is there another way of normalizing the input data into the desired format?

Answer (score 1):

The play below

```
tasks:
  - set_fact:
      devices1: "{{ devices1|default([]) + [ item ] }}"
    with_together:
      - "{{ input|dict2items|sort|selectattr('key', 'search', 'device_name')|list }}"
      - "{{ input|dict2items|sort|selectattr('key', 'search', 'volume_id')|list }}"
      - "{{ input|dict2items|sort|selectattr('key', 'search', 'volume_size')|list }}"
      - "{{ input|dict2items|sort|selectattr('key', 'search', 'volume_type')|list }}"
  - include_tasks: loop-devices.yml
    loop: "{{ devices1 }}"
  - debug:
      var: devices2
```

with include file loop-devices.yml

```
- set_fact:
    dev: {}
- set_fact:
    dev: "{{ dev|combine({dev_item.key.split('.').2:dev_item.value}) }}"
  loop: "{{ item }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: dev_item
- set_fact:
    devices2: "{{ devices2|default([]) + [ dev ] }}"
```

gives:

```
"devices2": [
    {
        "device_name": "/dev/xvdc", 
        "volume_id": "vol-00000000000000000", 
        "volume_size": "120", 
        "volume_type": "standard"
    }, 
    {
        "device_name": "/dev/xvde", 
        "volume_id": "vol-11111111111111111", 
        "volume_size": "80", 
        "volume_type": "standard"
    }, 
    {
        "device_name": "/dev/xvdf", 
        "volume_id": "vol-22222222222222222", 
        "volume_size": "50", 
        "volume_type": "standard"
    }
]
```